# Can you move an S3 bucket trigger from a previous function to a new function in Serverless Framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, infrastructure-as-code

I have a Lambda that has a bucket trigged attached. I am creating a 2nd function, and want to add this trigger to the 2nd function and remove it from the first

Previously:

```
functions:
  func1:
    handler: src/func1/func1.handler
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:custom.bucketname}
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          existing: true
      - sqs:
          arn: !GetAtt queue.Arn
          batchSize: 1
```

Now:

```
functions:
  func1:
    handler: src/func1/func1.handler
    events: []

  func2:
    handler: src/func2/func2.handler
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:custom.bucketname}
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          existing: true
      - sqs:
          arn: !GetAtt queue.Arn
          batchSize: 1
```

However whenever I try to deploy, I get:

```
Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Configurations overlap. Configurations on the same bucket cannot share a common event type. See details in CloudWatch Log: ...
```

It doesnt seem to firstly be removing the trigger from the first function when I redeploy.

Comment: Do two updates? Remove it from the first, re-deploy, add it to the second, re-deploy.

Comment: That worked! Seems like a bit of a bug that it works that way - alas, your workaround is correct!

Comment: Agree that it would be nice if it could detect what is basically a swap and just handle it.

Answer (score 0):

So Serverless isn't intelligent enough to know you've moved it, you need to first tear down the original and then spin up the new one.